# d3 js not displaying treemap nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I am working on creating a treemap using d3 js and vue js from a .json file. I have followed countless tutorials online and do exactly as the teacher does. However when I load this into my local server the data does not display at all. Would this be a problem with chrome or my actual .json file? Thank you for any help.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div> {{ title }} 

      <svg class="graph" id="treemap" width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 220">

        <g transform="translate(0,10)">
        </g>

      </svg>


    </div>
    

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";

export default {
  name: "App",
  
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Warehouse sizes',
      width: 960,
      height: 530,
      
    };
  },
  

  mounted(){
  //calls funciton to create treemap 
  this.createTreemap()

  },

  methods: {

  createTreemap() {
       //need to load the data
    d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BrennanAdams/treemap/master/warehouses.json").then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)

      //creating the treemap and its properties
      var treemapLayout = d3.treemap()

        treemapLayout.size([400,200])
        treemapLayout.paddingTop(20)
        treemapLayout.paddingInner(2)
        treemapLayout.round(true)
        treemapLayout.tile(d3.treemapSquarify.ratio(2) ); // Squarify, Slice, SliceDice, Binary

      //reformating the data to fit hierarchy layout
      var root = d3.hierarchy(data)
      root.sum(d => d.value)
      root.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)

      //finalizing treemap
      treemapLayout(root)

      console.log(root.descendants())
      var treemapNodes = d3.select("#treemap g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(root.leaves())
        .enter()
        .append('g').attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('transform', d => 'translate('+[d.x0, d.y0]+')')
        //.call(handleEvents)

        treemapNodes
        .append('rect')
        .classed('the-node', true)
        .attr("width", d => d.x1 - d.x0)
        .attr("height", d => d.y1 - d.y0)
        .style("fill", "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)")
        .style('stroke', "#2f2f2f")

        treemapNodes
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .attr('dx', d => 12)
        .attr('dy', d => 14)
        .text( d => d.data.name);

    })
  }

  }
}
</script>
```

```
{
    "warehouses":[
        {
            "id":4,
            "name":"Goimek",
            "value":354,
            "idParent":0,
            "nameParent":"",
            "locationInfo":[
            {
                "id":19,
                "name":"Puerta 4",
                "value":354
            }],
            "warehouseChildrenInfo":[]
        },
        {
            "id":5,
            "name":"Karpa",
            "value":167,
            "idParent":0,
            "nameParent":"",
            "locationInfo":[
            {
                "id":24,
                "name":"Karpa",
                "value":167
            }],
            "warehouseChildrenInfo":[]
        },
        {
            "id":6,
            "name":"Wec",
            "value":145,
            "idParent":0,
            "nameParent":"",
            "locationInfo":[
            {
                "id":25,
                "name":"WEC",
                "value":115
            }],
            "warehouseChildrenInfo":[
            {
                "id":1009,
                "name":"BIGUMETRIK",
                "value":30,
                "idParent":0,
                "nameParent":"",
                "locationInfo":[
                {
                    "id":1015,
                    "name":"BIGUMETRIK",
                    "value":30
                }],
                "warehouseChildrenInfo":[]
            }]
        },
        
        {
            "id":1037,
            "name":"PROVEEDOR",
            "value":10,
            "idParent":0,
            "nameParent":"",
            "locationInfo":[
            {
                "id":1553,
                "name":"PROVEEDOR Lehenetsitako kokapena",
                "value":10
            },
            {
                "id":1554,
                "name":"PIKUMEK S.L",
                "value":10
            },
            {
                "id":1555,
                "name":"TENKOR S.L",
                "value":10
            },
            {
                "id":1556,
                "name":"ZUMELTXU S.L",
                "value":10
            }],
            "warehouseChildrenInfo":[]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please add the code into the question, and not a link to a remote location. The link may become stale and not be referencable in the future.

Comment: Please paste the json data and code here instead of pasting image.

Answer (score -1):

d3 tree map does not support regular json format. You should convert your json to supporting format.

Comment: you could improve your answer by providng documentation to support your claim, and an example of what "the supporting format" is.